# how to get option property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```js
interface Input {
    necessaryA: string;
    necessaryB: string;
    optionA?: string;
    optionB?: string;
}

type defaultInputProperty = {
    optionA: string;
    optionB: string;
}

function handle(input: Input) {
    const defaultValues: defaultInputProperty = {
        optionA: 'defaultA',
        optionB: 'defaultB',
    }
    const actualInput: Required<Input> = { ...defaultValues, ...input };
    // do something with actualInput
}
```

How to declare `defaultInputProperty` so that it will be correct when declaration of `Input` changes?
More concretely,`defaultInputProperty` needs to add property `optionC` when `Input` has a new option property `optionC` and `defaultInputProperty` doesn't need to add property `necessaryC` when `Input` has a new necessary property `necessaryC`.
In other words,`defaultInputProperty` has all option property in `Input` and no necessary property in `Input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should be able to define it like this:

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never }[keyof T];

type defaultInputProperty = {
    [K in OptionalKeys<Input>]: Exclude<Input[K], undefined>;
}
```

This works if you have the compiler flag `strictNullChecks` enabled.

`defaultInputProperty` will have the following type:

```
type defaultInputProperty = {
    optionA: string;
    optionB: string;
}
```

**Edit: Explanation for `-?`**

The type of optional parameters and properties change when `--strictNullChecks` is enabled. Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#optional-parameters-and-properties

The following:

```
interface Input {
    necessaryA: string;
    necessaryB: string;
    optionA?: string;
    optionB?: string;
}
```

becomes

```
interface Input {
    necessaryA: string;
    necessaryB: string;
    optionA?: string | undefined;
    optionB?: string | undefined;
}
```

If we omit the `-?` then `OptionalKeys<Input>` will mean the following type:

```
"optionA" | "optionB" | undefined
```

When we try to use this in `defaultInputProperty`'s `[K in OptionalKeys<Input>]`, it will give an error `Type '"optionA" | "optionB" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.` as property names can't be of type `undefined.`

If we define `OptionalKeys<T>` with the `-?`, then `OptionalKeys<Input>` will now mean:

```
"optionA" | "optionB"
```

The explanation for this can be found in TypeScript 2.8 release notes which describes the `?` mapped type modifier in more detail: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers

> Note that in `--strictNullChecks` mode, when a homomorphic mapped type removes a `?` modifier from a property in the underlying type it also removes `undefined` from the type of that property:
>
> ```
> type Foo = { a?: string };  // Same as { a?: string | undefined }
> type Bar = Required<Foo>;  // Same as { a: string }
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much.But I don't understand the function of `-?`,can you explain more?